# Varying behavior when using named pipe with background process

Tags: bash, background-process, named-pipes

I'm having a hard time understanding named pipes. I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

function a_or_b {
   echo 'func begins'

   while true; do
      echo 'loop begins'

      read -s -n 1; echo $?
      case $REPLY in
         'a') return 0 ;;
         'b') return 1 ;;
      esac
   done

   echo 'func ends'
}

mkfifo pipe
a_or_b <pipe &
```

Now what I was expecting this script to do is:

1. enter `a_or_b` and therefore print `func begin`
2. enter the loop and therefore print `loop begins`
3. read an *EOF* from *stdin*, and therefore from `pipe`(as I have not written anything to `pipe`) and therefore print `1` as `$?`
4. not match on either case-clause and therefore go back to step 2

When running this script though I get no output and my terminal simply prints its next prompt.

---

If I redirect an *echo* into `pipe` **before** calling `a_or_b`:

```
...

mkfifo pipe
echo 'x' > pipe
a_or_b <pipe &
```

... the script doesn't stop running and I can keep entering characters (including `a` and 'b') in the terminal to no effect. So I have to end the script using *^C*.

---

If I redirect an *echo* into `pipe` **after** calling `a_or_b`:

```
...

mkfifo pipe
a_or_b <pipe &
echo 'x' > pipe
```

... I get the following output:

```
func begins
loop begins
0
loop begins
0
loop begins
1
loop begins
1
loop begins
1
```

This is basically the behavior I expected from not *echoing* anything to `pipe`. The function begins, goes into the loop, reads the `x` and `\n` characters from the `echo` (corresponding to the two `0`s in the output) and then keeps looping forever while failing to read any characters. And if I *echo* `a` or `b` into the pipe, the function ends.

---

What is causing all of these different behaviors?

Comment: Simply *opening* the read end of a pipe, not actually attempting to read from it, blocks a process until the other end is opened for writing;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a_or_b <pipe &
```

Redirections are processed before starting commands. The shell blocks trying to open `pipe` for reading. From the [mkfifo(3) man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/mkfifo):

> Opening a FIFO for reading normally blocks until some other process opens the same FIFO for writing, and vice versa.

The shell can't proceed until another process opens the FIFO for writing. Only then will it finish setting up the redirection and actually call `a_or_b`.

---

```
echo 'x' > pipe
a_or_b <pipe &
```

Unfortunately this has the same, but inverse problem. The shell can't proceed past the `> pipe` redirection until another process opens the FIFO for reading. It never gets to the `echo` nor the second line that would read from the pipe.

---

```
a_or_b <pipe &
echo 'x' > pipe
```

Hopefully you can now see why this version works. The background shell tries to read from the pipe and blocks. The foreground shell, a separate process, writes to it. Aha! Two processes have opened the pipe, one for reading and one for writing. They can now both proceed. The birds sing and everybody is happy.

Comment: The `mkfifo` man page states that "[a FIFO] has to be open at both ends simultaneously before you can proceed to do any input or output operations on it. Opening a FIFO for reading normally blocks until some other process opens the same FIFO for writing, and vice versa." Why does the the first-function-call-then-echo-to-pipe version fulfill this requirement? And why does the first-echo-to-pipe-then-function-call version not? I guess I don't understand what you mean by "The shell blocks trying to open `pipe` for reading."

Comment: Because of the `&`. The working one has the first line run in the background so the fact that it blocks doesn't stop the second line from running. The background processed is blocked, which is okay.

Comment: If you moved the `&` to the first line in the middle case then it would also work.